# how to remove assocative array keys and add default array keys PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
$arr = array(3=>'test',6=>'test 2');
```

i want to make it

```
$arr = array(0=>'test',1=>'test 2');
```

what is the best way . is there any php function to do that .

thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `array_values` :

```
$arr = array(3=>'test',6=>'test 2');
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php